# ColdFusion cfset issue

Tags: coldfusion

I am new to ColdFusion. Anyone know why this code is not working. When I leave the form null it is not showing 100 in the database.

```
<cfif isdefined("FORM.Percentage")>
  <cfset Form.Percentage = #Form.Percentage#>
<cfelse>
  <cfset Form.Percentage = 100>
</cfif>

<cfquery name="percent" datasource ="abc">
Insert into Employees
  (Percentage)
Values
  (#Form.Percentage#)    
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Even tho the form is null it is still passed into the page. You should instead check if len( trim( form.percentage )) or isNumeric( form.Percentage ) instead of isDefined() which is why your form.percentage is never set to 100.

Comment: what is it showing in the database? Try surrounding the cfquery by <cfoutput> tags

Comment: @MattBusche: you are right

Comment: @DG3, cfquery has an implicit cfoutput tag.  In other words, you don't need one.

Comment: Do you know why now it always says a hundred and never the input number?

Comment: @user2967577 what code are you using?

Comment: *leave the form null* It is not `null`. It is empty, which is quite different.

Answer (score 14):

If you have a textbox it is submitted to the form even if it's left blank, so you want to check if the field was left blank. If it was then you can set the default.

You'll also want to do some server side validation that the value is a number and use `cfqueryparam` for inserting your value into the database.

```
<cfif NOT len(trim(FORM.Percentage))>
  <cfset Form.Percentage = 100>
<cfif>

<cfquery result="percent" datasource="abc">
Insert into Employees (Percentage)
Values (
  <cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_integer" value="#Form.Percentage#">
)
</cfquery>
```

When using `cfquery` with an INSERT the name attribute doesn't provide anything. Using `result` would allow you to view some data about the query if needed, but generally it shouldn't be used.

You could also have dumped `form` to the screen by using `<cfdump var="#form#">` to see what it was returning. If you want to check that the key exists for a radio button or checkbox you can use `structKeyExists(form,'myCheckbox')` rather than using `isDefined()`.

Comment: The name attribute in the cfquery tag does indeed provide something.  It allows the code to run without throwing an error.  In other words, it's a required attribute.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html

Comment: @DanBracuk no, it's not required for an `INSERT` statement. The docs may say it is, but it's not. Hasn't been required since at least CF8.

Comment: @user2967577 - Since you mentioned being new to ColdFusion, never use raw client variables in queries. Always use [`cfqueryparam`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) like in the example above. Among its other benefits, it protects your database from SQL injection.